# Transposing with header row

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets I'm trying to transpose a list of items in rows to display as columns. I am looking for a way to transpose the `Category` field to act as a header row that extends over all the items of that category in the transposed copy.

(Though not absolutely necessary, if there's a way to use conditional formatting to have the background color change for each category that would also be a huge bonus).

Here's a demo image:

[image: Transpose with Headers Demo Image]

and a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tqGC0qEa8vpValsmvYWiQu1nUbBjuLGxvQfBk58VqMQ/edit?usp=sharing) of what I'm trying to do.

If at all possible I'd like to accomplish this without using scripts!

Comment: Sorry. An error on my part. Just fixed. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

A simple transpose does this:

```
  =TRANSPOSE(B2:D7)
```